Set max limit for async fs operations? (EMFILE: too many open files)
I am writing some plugin for neovim in lua. At some point plugin reads some list of files, and this list's size can be >1000. Function that reads file is
local uv = vim.loop
function utils.read_file(path, callback)
  uv.fs_open(path, "r", 438, function(err, fd)
    assert(not err, err)
    assert(fd, fd)
      uv.fs_fstat(fd, function(s_err, stat)
        assert(not s_err, s_err)
        assert(stat, stat)
        uv.fs_read(fd, stat.size, 0, function(r_err, data)
          assert(not r_err, r_err)
          uv.fs_close(fd, function(c_err)
            assert(not c_err, c_err)
            callback(data)
          end)
        end)
      end)
    end)
end

and it is called from loop like
for _, path in ipairs(paths) do
  utils.read_file(path, some_process_func)
end

I faced with error
... EMFILE: too many open files: ...

when size of paths was too big.
So question is how to deal with this situation? I tried to make kinda semaphore which looks like
local sema = 10
for _, path in ipairs(paths) do
  while sema == 0 do end
  sema = sema - 1
  utils.read_file(path, function()
    sema = sema + 1
    --...
  end)
end

but it only causes infinite loop and my neoviw stucks forever. My requirements to this part of code is async fs operations, so i don't want to just make it sync and run in other thread. I look for some queue to overflowed async operations will be located in while other operations is working.
